# Angular 2 - add attribute in template based on input value

Tags: javascript, angular

I want add `required` to input only if it was set in input.

```
<input-block 
    name="formName" 
    label="my label" 
    placeholder="test" 
    required
></input-block>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-block',
    inputs: ['name', 'label', 'placeholder', 'required'],
    template: `
        <label class="input-block">
            <span class="name">{{label}}</span>
            <input type="text" 
                name="{{name}}"
                placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
                <!-- no idea: {{required ? 'required : ''}} -->
            >
        </label>
    `
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like that

```
<input type="text" 
        #myInput
        name="{{name}}"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        [attr.required]="myInput.value ? "required" : null">
```

Comment: `attr.required` is what I was looking for. Thanks. In my expample `[attr.required]="required">` works as I want.